# Jersey : response with List<DBObject>

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jersey, dbobject

I want to send Json with Jersey.
I use mongoDb.

My function to return my objects :

```
public static List<DBObject> getAll(){
    List<DBObject> toReturn = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    DBCollection coll = Db.databse.getCollection("Roles");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
    try {
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            toReturn.add(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

And my jersey method to return json :

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAll(){
      return Response.status(200).entity(Role.getAll()).build();
}
```

I use POSTMAN.
POSTMAN receives 200 but not my JSON.
If somebody can help me.
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution :
My function to parse dbCollection to List<>

```
public static List<Role> getAll(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Role> toReturn = new ArrayList<Role>();
    DBCollection coll = Db.databse.getCollection("Roles");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
    try {
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(cursor.next());
            Role r = gson.fromJson(cursor.next().toString(),Role.class);
            toReturn.add(r);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

My function to return List<> to json response :

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public Response getAll(){
    List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<Role>();
    roleList = Role.getAll();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(roleList);
    return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
}
```

Hope that will help somebody in this world.